# My chapter 1 is repeated in pdf but tex has only chapter 1 one time, how to avoid repeatition

Tags: pdftex

I have one quastion regarding repeatition, chapter 1 is repeating twice but tex is only one, how to remove this ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: For sure you are doing something to change the default output of a standard book class. What exactly? That is another history, at least with this data, but ok, I'll play the guessing game: My bet is you deal with the headers and now you see the chapter title in the top margin, close to the chapter title that is only one ( the other is just the header, that by default is omitted in the chapter page). Did I get it right?

Comment: Do you mean you write `\chapter{Chapter 1}` only once but you get something like `Chapter 1 Chapter 1` in the output? That's because `\chapter{}` expects the title of the chapter as its argument e.g. `\chapter{First}` and then produces, say, `Chapter 1 First`. The expectation is that `First` will actually be some description e.g. `Method` and LaTeX counts the chapters for you.